# MEAN stack, cannot find module 'request'

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, meanjs, mean.io

I'm new to mean stack world, I installed mongoDB and nodejs

```
node -v  => v4.4.3
npm -v   => 2.15.1
mongo -version => MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6
```

then followed MEAN [installation guide](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/wiki/Installation) to install it.
after many faults I can run gult and have a response.
now when ever I try to run any command with mean, I get following error:

```
module.js:327
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'request'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/lib/controllers/anonymized-data.js:8:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

I tried with: `sudo npm install  request`
but still getting same issue !! can any one guide me please? thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
after running command given by @Alexander Mac, I got following result

[image: looks like still not working :(]

it's still same status :( . and without sudo I got lots or errors @Seth :P

Comment: Try reinstall `mean-cli`: `sudo npm un -g mean-cli && sudo npm cache clean && sudo npm i -g mean-cli `

Comment: still having the same error :(

Comment: I've checked `mean-cli` package it has a bug. The authors forget to include `request` module in `package.json`: [https://github.com/linnovate/mean-cli/blob/master/package.json](https://github.com/linnovate/mean-cli/blob/master/package.json). You can create an issue about that on their site.

Comment: To resolve the problem locally go to `/usr/lib/node_modules/mean-cli` and run `sudo npm i` command there.

Comment: As a side note, don't use sudo... https://blog.explosionpills.com/dont-use-sudo-with-npm/

Comment: please check question update

Comment: I made a mistake, use `sudo npm i request` to install request module.

Comment: @alexmac  thanks for your help, looks like it's fine now. please add it as an answer to accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mean-cli` package has a bug. The authors forget to include `request` module in package.json: [look here](https://github.com/linnovate/mean-cli/blob/master/package.json). You can create an issue about that on their site.

To resolve the problem locally go to `/usr/lib/node_modules/mean-cli` and run: `sudo npm i request` to install missing `request` module.

Comment: The answer by sudhan is a better approach.

Answer (score 4):

Alex is right about 'request' not being part of the package. That said, instead of messing out with the install manually, it might be far easier to *install a previous known good version*

For e.g., you can try: `sudo npm i -g mean-cli@0.12.1`

Comment: good idea also (in case I'm in harry), but still want to solve this issue ;)

Answer (score 2):

I use nvm to manage node.
I go to /home/ougwen1235/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.4/lib/node_modules/mean-cli and run npm install request --save.Then, the problem was solved.